# How to Merge two Git repositories using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, git-merge, tortoisegit

Problem point:
Want to create a white-label(copy) of a project in a new git repository, but wanted to merge all changes and fixes made in main repository.

**NOTE:** Git branches are sufficient for handling white labels, but if project demands separate repositories, then this solution is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

## Projects with white label but wanted to have a bridge between them.

Project names: "Main"(your main project), "WhiteLabel"(your copy of main project)

Conditions for successful git repo merge : Structure of the code shall be similar for both existing projects.

## Existing White Label Repo?

Steps:
1. Open "WhiteLabel" git project and create a new branch with its "master" branch as its head as master or any other branch.
(in project folder -> right-click -> select git -> create branch)
[image: Create Branch]

2. Switch/Checkout to new branch if not in the branch.
3. Right click and click on Git Sync

[image: Git Sync]

4. A window with git settings will open, then click on Manage button.

[image: Manage]
5. Enter the values 
   Remote: Enter local-remote name.
   Url: Give your "Main" project path with ".git" folder selected in it.
   Click on Add New/Save
[image: Adding local remote repo]

6. Now type "master" or other branch name of the "Main" repository, and say pull.
   [image: Pull data from other repo]
7. If merge conflicts occur, then select the right hand section which is updated changes in "WhiteLabel" repository.

Done!

## Updating changes

Changes in "Main" Repository can be pulled as follows
1. open "WhiteLablMergeRepo" branch
2. Just right click and pull the changes.
3. Once changes are pulled, merge them to your "WhiteLabel" branch.

## New White Label Repo?

1. Create your "WhiteLabel" Repository.
2. Follow steps mentioned above. but you will not face Step 7 as the current branch is empty.
   Remain is same.